# mysql query insert error

Tags: mysql

The INSERT into staffprofiles mysql query (near the bottom of the code) is getting the "or die" statement triggered. Can anyone see why? The first one into staffusers is fine. Am I breaking a rule by having 2 insert commands or something? If so, is there another way to code what I am trying to do? Thank you in advance for any help.

Also, I will be address SQL injection and other items shortly. I just want to get this figured out first. Thanks.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>XXXXXXX</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>

      <body>
         <div id="back">
         </div>


        <div id="wrapper">

                <div id="header">
                 <div id="logout">
                <?php
              include 'header.php';
                ?>


                 </div>
                  <span><b>XXXXXXX</b>XXXXXX</span>
                </div>

                <?php
                include 'menu.php';

if (isset ($_POST['submit']))

{
}

else

{
echo "not set";
}


$user=$_POST['username'];
$pass1=$_POST['pass1'];
$pass2=$_POST['pass2'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$user=strip_tags($user);
$email=strip_tags($email);
$pass1=strip_tags($pass1);

$isemail = "SELECT * from staffusers where email ='$email'";
$isemail2 = mysql_query($isemail) or die ("could not query email in table");
$isemail3 = mysql_fetch_array($isemail2);

if ($isemail3)
{
echo "That email address is already registered.<br>";
echo "<a href='forgotpassword.php'>Forgot passsword.</a><br>";
echo "<a href='staffregisterform.php'>Go back to register under a different email address.</a>";
exit;
}

if ($email == "" || $user == "" || $pass1 == ""  || $pass2 == "")
{
echo "please complete all fields before submitting<br>";
echo "<a href='staffregisterform.php'>Go Back</a>";
exit;
}

if (strlen($pass1)<6)
{
echo "Your password must be at least 6 characters in length.<br>";
echo "<a href='staffregisterform.php'>Go Back</a>";
exit;
}

if ($pass1 == $pass2)
{
$isplayer = "SELECT * from staffusers where username ='$user'";
$isplayer2 = mysql_query($isplayer) or die ("could not query user in table");
$isplayer3 = mysql_fetch_array($isplayer2);

if ($isplayer3)
{
echo "The username ''$user'' is already taken. Please try another username.<br>";
echo "<a href='staffregisterform.php'>Go Back</a>";
exit;
}

if (strlen($user)>16 || strlen($user)<2)
{
echo "Your username must be be at 2 two characters and at most, 16 characters.<br>";
echo "<a href='staffregisterform.php'>Go Back</a>";
exit;
}
}

else
{
echo "The passwords do not match.<br>";
echo "<a href='staffregisterform.php'>Go Back</a>";
exit;
}

$pass1=MD5($pass1);

$register = "INSERT INTO staffusers (username, password, email) VALUES ('$user', '$pass1', '$email')";
mysql_query($register) or die ("staffusers.");

$profile = "INSERT INTO staffprofiles (username, email) VALUES ('$user', '$email')";
mysql_query($profile) or die ("staffprofiles.");

echo "Thank you for registering, $user.<br>";
echo "<a href='index.php'>Login</a>";

?>
```

Comment: did you check your table name and field names that you are using are valid....

Comment: Use mysql_error instead of the die and see what's the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have valid fieldnames and table names then try;

```
$profile = mysql_query("INSERT INTO staffprofiles (username, email) VALUES ('$user', '$email')");

// use some value directly to check as:
$user = "Tester";
$email= "something@test.com";
$profile = mysql_query("INSERT INTO staffprofiles (username, email) VALUES ('$user', '$email')");

//if this value gets inserted then you have problem in $user variables value
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Sudhir - I made those changes and it still didn't go through. The table and column names are correct. I will try the mysql_error and Aurelio recommended...

Comment: BTW - the updated code that I tried...

$profile = "INSERT INTO staffprofiles (username, email) VALUES ('tester', 'tester@gmail.com')";
echo $profile."<br>";
mysql_query($profile) or die ("staffprofiles.");

Comment: and the result...INSERT INTO staffprofiles (username, email) VALUES ('tester', 'tester@gmail.com')
staffprofiles.